# Adding range slider to Onsen-UI

Tags: onsen-ui

It is not supported out of the box by Onsen-UI. What is the simplest way to add such functionality? Example: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, OnsenUI hasn't provided anything like that yet. But you can make some changes to OnsenUI and get a similar slider. Please refer to the example in the link below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPRBwQ

```
<div class="test" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  {{firstRanger}}<input type="range" class="range1" ng-model="firstRanger"><input type="range" class="range" ng-model="secondRanger" min=100 max=200>{{secondRanger}}  
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was asking about range slider, with 2 drag handles

Comment: Oh. Sorry I misunderstood your question. At the moment, I think OnsenUI hasn't provided anything like that yet.